# How to Find Ffifth Youngest Employee by DOB in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

What will be sql query for the fifth youngest employee?

Below query is wrong? please help

```
SELECT EmpID, EmpName, EMPDOB,
   ORDER BY EMPDOB DESC
WHERE ROWNUMBER = 5
FROM dbo.EMP
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPDOB ASC) AS rownumber,
    EmpID, EmpName, EMPDOB
  FROM EMPLOYEE
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 5
```

Comment: Please explain the answer.  Keep in mind this answer may be referenced many times by many different people.  By providing details about what this is doing and why, you help the current question and future users.  SQL only answers which provide the correct answer are nice; but knowing what row_number is why it has to be wrapped in a derived table  provide a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will solve your problem:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    T.EmpID
    , T.EmpName
    , T.EMPDOB 
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.EMP ORDER BY EMPDOB DESC) AS T
```

Note: This solution assumes that EMPDOB is in a date or integer based format.

Comment: Correctness not guaranteed because there is no order by clause for the outer "top".